# New Russian Sokol space suit

Tags: soyuz-spacecraft, spacesuits, sokol-spacesuit

According to the pictures of the mission Soyuz MS-03, the crew is wearing a new "Sokol" space suit. The previous crew was still wearing the 1980 "vintage" KV2 version.

[image: Soyuz MS-03 crew before launch]
[image: Soyuz MS-02 crew before launch]

Any information about this new model?

Comment: This question is attracting close votes for being too broad. Have you done *any* research yourself? Do you have *specific* questions about the suit?

Comment: Yes there is some information -1)  there are at least two known photographs, and 2) the suits are off-white in color with blue trim, 3) they can be used to maintain pressure in a vacuum if used correctly, for limited periods of time, 4) they are designed and manufactured in Russia. Can you narrow your question - this one seems too broad and open-ended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I understand this is just a new **overcoat** as an additional insulation for cold environments, underneath wich they still wear their usual Cокол suit. It consists of several pieces which can easily be removed by opening some velcro strips.

[image]

Source:

And http://www.russianspaceweb.com/soyuz-ms-03.html